# Populate column "Type" based on sum for the same PolicyNumber

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I need to create a column `Type`. 
If `PolicyNumber` has negative `Premium`  then column `Type` should have value of 1
            AND
If the SUM of `Premium` for the same `PolicyNumber` is <= 0 then it should be 1 for both `PolicyNumber`

```
PolicyNumber  AgentName   Premium   Transaction
   A           Brien       1,000     New Business
   A           Brien      -1,000     Cancelled
   B           Michael     500       New Business
   C           David       600       New Business
   D           Tom         800       New Business
   D           Tom        -800       Endorsement
```

**Desirable Outcome:**

```
 PolicyNumber  AgentName   Premium   Transaction      Type
   A           Brien       1,000     New Business      1
   A           Brien      -1,000     Cancelled         1
   B           Michael     500       New Business      0
   C           David       600       New Business      0
   D           Tom         800       New Business      1
   D           Tom        -800       Endorsement       1
```

Comment: A case statement and inline select could do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a case we can set this value by use of an or and a correlated query select.

```
SELECT PolicyNumber
     , AgentName
     , Premium
     , [Transaction]
     , Case when Premium < 0 OR (SELECT sum(B.Premium) 
                                 FROM tblName B 
                                 WHERE B.PolicyNumber = A.PolicyNumber) <= 0 then 1 else 0 end as Type
FROM tblName A
```

Though this above line by line select can be slow.  may be best to get the totals in a subquery.

```
SELECT A.PolicyNumber
     , A.AgentName
     , A.Premium
     , A.[Transaction]
     , Case when A.Premium < 0 OR B.SP <=0 then 1 else 0 end as Type
FROM tblName A
INNER JOIN (SELECT sum(Premium) SP, PolicyNumber 
            FROM  tblName 
            GROUP BY PolicyNumber) B
 on A.PolicyNumber = B.Policy_Number
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Its amazing what you did

Answer (score 2):

Try this( sql server 2008 +)

```
With policyData as(
Select policyNumber,agentName,Premium, transaction, sum(premium) over (partition by policyNumber) sumPremium from yourTable
)
Select policyNumber, agentName, premium, transaction, case when premium<0 or sumPremium<=0 then 1 Else 0 End as type from policyData
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.*, case when Premium < 0 then 1 when s <= 0 then 1 else 0 end as type from (
    select your_table.*, sum(Premium) over(partition by PolicyNumber) as s from your_table
) t
```

Comment: If this works with two froms like the above; I've learned something new.

Comment: @xQbert - I don't get what you mean when you said `with two froms` ?

Comment: Nevermind.... I only saw one query with two froms and though there's no Way this can work...  I now see the inline view; thus there are two queries and two froms needed.

Comment: @xQbert - No problem )